# connecting data points of different series in scatter chart (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, statistics, scatter-plot, evaluation

Below is a scatter chart that displays two data sets using excel. the blue data set are **observed(actual)** location coordinates of detected small cars on a world plane. The orange data set represent the same location coordinates, however **reconstructed** using inverse mapping process which consists of many processes like camera calibration, finding camera pose, etc.
[image: Scatter]

**So my question is**

is there a way i can connect every blue point with its correspondent orange one in Excel ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the comment. Yes it is a statistical question

Comment: @BigBen. I know that. However, i rarely get answers on the stack exchange. Thats why i post the question here:).

Comment: @BigBen. I've changed the content of the question. Hope you could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for misunderstanding problem.

We will will start by creating two series, one for observed and another for reconstructed.

We then create a new series for each observed and reconstructed pair. Each of these series will have a line connecting them.

We then order the series such that the first two series we created, of the observed and reconstructed data sets, are brought to the front.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the comment. what i want is to connect between a reconstructed and observed data point and not between reconstructed pairs

Comment: So this mean i need to create a series for each pair of (actual/observed)?

Comment: @k.jbaili  that is how i solved this yes, if there is an onerous number of pairs to chart, you can use vba. edited  response as i realize it could have been much clearer.